# What are examples of complex communication protocols that do not need a 7 layer OSI model to describe them?

Tags: communication, protocol, model, networking

I am trying to dissect an existing design of a custom communication protocol that uses infrared pulses to communicate between only two devices. The design has dozens of small RTL modules, but there is no clear grouping as per the OSI model.

I know that not every communication protocol is complex enough to warrant a 7-layer model to be described.

What are examples of complex popular communication protocols or stacks that are not described using a 7-layer model, but with fewer layers?

Since some layers are redundant, they are never needed in conceptualizing the communication system. I will study them to get an idea of how a communication protocol can be described using less than 7 layers.

Comment: Take a look at NFS (network file system), and our neighbors stackoverflow/superuser.

Comment: I don't think your question makes sense. It sounds like your notion of "complex" is anything that needs a 7 layer model so by your definition anything that needs fewer layers wouldn't qualify as "complex".

Comment: Something needing less than 7 layers is certainly not as complex as one which does need 7 layers

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 that is not true. 7 very simple layers are way less complex as 6 complex, interlinked layers.

Comment: For point to point communications you may only need the bottom two or three layers of that 7 layer model. For example the Physical Layer (e.g. the Ethernet MAC and associated electronics) and the Data Link Layer (packet format inc. from/to addresses and a CRC to detect corruption).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requests an open ended list, while stack exchange sites are reserved only for questions which can have specific answers.

Comment: I just need a few examples, where else am I supposed to ask this question?

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP is usually described as having four or five layers, depending on whom you ask, see [RFC 1122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1122/).

The Arpanet Reference Model ([RFC 871](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc871/)) makes do with three layers.

Also, there is never a "need" to use the OSI model's seven layers to describe a protocol. It's a mainly theoretical framework that comes in handy sometimes when communicating with others, but it is only as relevant as you want it to be (opinion warning here).

It is not a perfect model for all existing communication protocols, and there's no law saying that you have to use it, or that all communication protocols should be described in its terms and be made to "fit".

Comment: and in all honesty, it's not the perfect model for many modern communication protocols, as there's often pretty strong links between the layers that look so strictly separated in the OSI layer model.

Comment: Quite so. Strangely, there are people who hardly dare say that out loud.